# how to connect codeigniter with ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I need to connect codeigniter with a ajax post

- the first problem was the use of jquery.min.js, if you use ajax you cannot use this version of jquery, you need to use the full version.
- Then I tried to do all the jquery code in parts to go testing its functionality.
- I think the problem is in the url of the ajax call or in the controller

this is my view (very simple)

```
<form action="#" id="form">
    <label for="">nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">

    <label for="">apellido</label>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" id="apellido">

    <label for="">cedula</label>
    <input type="text" name="cedula" id="cedula">

    <label for="">direccion</label>
    <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion"><br>

    <button class="btn btn-info" id="btn" type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").on('click', function (e) {
    // var data = $("#form").serialize();
    // alert("datos:" + data);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url('myController/formAjaxCrear')?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.nombre);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("something is wrong");
            }

        });
    });
});
```

my controller in the file myController

```
public function formAjaxCrear(){
    $data = [
        'nombre' => $this -> input -> post('nombre'),
        'apellido' => $this -> input -> post('apellido'),
        'cedula' => $this -> input -> post('cedula'),
        'direccion' => $this -> input -> post('cedula'),
    ];

    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

I expected to receive in the browser popup window: *Jessica*, if I fill the input nombre with that information. Why do I only receive the error message?

Comment: What is the Status of your AJAX Call in the Network Tab of the Console. 404 or 500?

Comment: i get this info: https://ibb.co/KK0WCB4

Comment: I'm testing the fail function and it tells me Requested JSON parse failed

Comment: Your request in Network Tab is for some reason GET instead of POST

Comment: Added Answer. This should help you.

Comment: A friend helped me verify what the problem was. I had two views loaded in one view, for example the bar view and the form view. Disabling the bar view, everything went very well. The problem in my opinion was that it had two html tags open and closed inside another html tag. thx so much for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make following changes to your code

1. You have button type as submit, this is actually submitting the form. You can change this in 2 ways. Either change the JS Method

a)

```
    $("#btn").on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();  //This will prevent submitting of form.
```

b) You can also do this by changing the type of button from submit to just button

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="btn" type="submit">enviar</button>
```

change above to

```
<button class="btn btn-info" id="btn" type="button">enviar</button>
```

2. For better standards, you should explicitly tell CodeIgnitor to return AJAX Data.
   You can do this by making following changes in `formAjaxCrear` method.

```
  header('Content-Type: application/json'); //This sends Headers and make sure that data type returned is JSON.
  echo json_encode($data);
```